# How to add dropdownlist to a td dynamically

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

We have an old ASP.NET MVC framework and we are in the progress of moving to .NET 5 MVC
The ViewModel that we receive from the controller contains several things but
one of these is called ListOfDayTypes and it's a list of SelectListItem

We use html table that we render dynamically and each of these td looks the same
except id,name and value

```
<td width="29" id="17_2021-1-2">                            
   <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[0].Value[1].ScheduleId" value="0">
   <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[0].Value[1].Date" value="2021-1-2">
   <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[0].Value[1].DayTypeId" value="0">
   <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[0].Value[1].HasChanged" value="false">
   <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[0].Value[1].ShiftTypeId" value="1008">
   <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[0].Value[1].ShiftTeamId" value="17">
  <a class="defaultScheduleLink" onclick="javascript:showDayTypes($(this));"> * </a>
</td>
```

When we click an anchor in a td cell we call function showDayTypes($(this) because we must show a dropdownlist
where we can select an item from.
This works fine in the old ASP.NET framework but we have trouble in .NET 5

In the old code we have the following:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   var ddlHtml = '@Html.Raw(Html.DropDownList("ddlDayType", Model.ListOfDayTypes, new { id="ddlDayType", @class="scheduleDDL",        onchange="onDayTypeChanged();"} ).ToString().Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, ""))';
</script>
```

When clicking in an anchor in td cell this showDayTypes code is called
As you can see we just use variable ddlHtml from `@Html.Raw(...)`
to populate the dropdown list to it's parent which is a td and
this works well.

```
function showDayTypes(link)
{
    var td = link.parent("td");
    link.remove(); 
    td.append(ddlHtml);
    var select = td.children("select");
    var option = select.children("option[text='" + link.text() + "']");
    select.val(option.val());
}
```

I have tried to use the same code in .NET 5 but I get
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.TagBuilder`
when I try to use `@Html.Raw`
It seems to me they have removed some good functionality in .NET 5 which is bad.

What is the best way to solve my problem so the dropdownlist
is displayed when clicking an anchor in a td and can select an item from the dropdownlist
as we could in the old ASP.NET framework

I have looked everywhere but no good solutions.

Comment: "I have tried to use the same code in .NET 5 but I get
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.TagBuilder." Please post the actual, complete error message.

Comment: As soon as I use @Html.Raw(Html.DropDownList("ddlDayType", Model.ListOfDayTypes)); I get the message back saying Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.TagBuilder

Comment: What do you mean "I get the message back" ? Are you talking about a compilation error, an exception, or something else?

Comment: If you're going to render the html server side anyway, just toggle visibility with JS / css classes. Otherwise I'd load the data as json and render client side with a moustache template or something.

Comment: Many thanks Rena I will accept you answer. It was new to me that backticts that are used around my dropdown return a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get the message back saying Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.TagBuilder

For this issue, you could change your code like below:

```
var ddlHtml = `@Html.DropDownList("ddlDayType", Model.ListOfDayTypes, new { id = "ddlDayType", @class = "scheduleDDL", onchange = "onDayTypeChanged();" })`;
```

**Note**: the symbol is  **`**   not single quote(').

Besides, your code seems also want to set link text as selected item. If so, modify like below:

```
<script>
    var ddlHtml = `@Html.DropDownList("ddlDayType", Model.ListOfDayTypes, new { id = "ddlDayType", @class = "scheduleDDL", onchange = "onDayTypeChanged();" })`;
    function showDayTypes(link) {
        var td = link.parent("td");
        link.remove();
        td.append(ddlHtml);
        var select = td.children("select");

        var option = select.children("option").filter(":contains('" + link.text()+"')");

        select.val(option.val());
    }
</script>
```

Result:

[image]